# projections Basemap and pyproj

Tags: coordinate-system, basemap, pyproj

I am struggling to understand the projections using **[pyproj](http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/)**.

for now my question is to understand the results of projection operations

I have following coordinates that I project on x,y

```
lon  = [3.383789, 5.822754]
lat = [48.920575, 53.72185]

# with Basemap 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
M = Basemap(projection='merc',ellps = 'WGS84')
q1, q2 = M(lon, lat)
print zip([x for x in q1], [x for x in q2])
# this gives me 
#[(20414190.011221122, 65799915.85232639), (20685694.35308374, 66653928.94762396)]

# with pyproj
from pyproj import Proj
p = Proj(proj='merc', ellps='WGS84',errcheck = True)
print p(3.383789, 48.920575), p(5.822754, 53.72185)
#this gives me 
#(376681.6684318804, 6229168.979819128) (648186.0102944968, 7083182.075116195)
```

why are the results different while I use the same projections parameters

as a newbie in geospatial data processing I apologize in advance for a question which may be trivial

P.S: I edited the questions following comments

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  One of our protocols is to ask only one question per Question so would you be able to use the edit button to revise the second one out and then research/ask it separately, please?

Comment: thanks PolyGeo. deleted second question, will ask it separately.

Comment: In the last line, you use p on pairs of lon1, lon2 instead of lon1,lat1. Are you sure about the order of lon and lat?

Comment: The second pairs look good now. What do you expect from `[x for x in q1]`?

Comment: @AndreJoost: thanks. I thought that since basemap takes a list of long and a list of lat, the zip would give the projections in (long,lat). so [x for x in q1] gives a list of all long with zip it ties them up to lats. Does this makes sense ?

Comment: Looking at the results, not. Google Mercator has an extent of +-20037508.34 for x and y, and your second coordinate is far to big for that. I don't konw much about Basemap, but the pyproj results look good.